# Routing to match a singular name instead of the plural generated by ':resources'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

In the 'config/routes.rb' of my RoR3 application I have this code

```
resources :users
```

so that I can go to `http://application.local/users/2`.

Anyway I would like to match for it `http://application.local/user/2`, but I don't know how to change the 'routes.rb' to do that.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Rails is mostly about convention over configuration. If you follow a convention (like the defaults you get when you choose to do resources :users) programming in Rails is going to be fun, otherwise it'll be an uphill battle generally.

Comment: @Aditya Sanghi: You're confusing "convention" with "religion". The idea of "convention over configuration" is to make it very easy to do the things most people want to do in most cases, not to make every other way of doing things hard. You just need to do a bit more work to do things differently from the conventional way. However, you might have a very good reason for doing so. In fact, in my experience, Rails is good in allowing you to deviate from convention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails does have [singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) but they're for routes which there is only one record/id which is being referenced (for example /profile to show the logged in user's profile).

If you're needing a normal resource (which can accept IDs), then you can use `:path` to change how the route looks:

```
resources :users, :path => "user"
```

Will give you these routes:

```
    users GET    /user(.:format)                    {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
          POST   /user(.:format)                    {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
 new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)                {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
edit_user GET    /user/:id/edit(.:format)           {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
     user GET    /user/:id(.:format)                {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
          PUT    /user/:id(.:format)                {:controller=>"users", :action=>"update"}
          DELETE /user/:id(.:format)                {:controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy"}
```